# Regex for parsing a shell command like strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse strings that look like shell commands. The general structure of these command is the following:

```
command value -arg1name arg1val -arg2name arg2val ... -argMname argMval
```

Here is an example,

```
abc cmdh1521 -x 123 -y sadg -zzz 563sd
```

I am using the Python re module to parse, search and group strings so that I get an output like this,

```
(command, value, ((-arg1name, arg1val), (arg2name, arg2val), ... (argMname, argMval))
```

I tried the following set of commands, but my output is not what I want it to be.

```
import re
cmd = "abc cmdh1521 -x 123 -y sadg -zzz 563sd"
_parser = r"^([a-z]+)\s{1}(\S*)((\s+\-[a-z]+\s{1}\S+)*)"
out = re.search(_parser, cmd)
print out.groups()
```

Here is the output I get

```
('abc', 'cmdh1521', ' -x 123 -y sadg -zzz 563sd', ' -zzz 563sd')
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can easily implement a non-regex solution, but I would like to know if there is a regex that can give me the kind of parsing I want?

Answer (score 2):

Then again split according to the space exists before `-`

```
>>> s = ('abc', 'cmdh1521', ' -x 123 -y sadg -zzz 563sd', ' -zzz 563sd')
>>> h = []
>>> for i in s:
    if '-' not in i:
        h.append(i)
    else:
        for j in re.split(r'\s+(?=-)', i):
            if j:
                h.append(j)


>>> h
['abc', 'cmdh1521', '-x 123', '-y sadg', '-zzz 563sd', '-zzz 563sd']
>>>
```

or

```
>>> cmd = "abc cmdh1521 -x 123 -y sadg -zzz 563sd"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)|(-\S+\s+\S+)', cmd)
[('abc', 'cmdh1521', ''), ('', '', '-x 123'), ('', '', '-y sadg'), ('', '', '-zzz 563sd')]
>>> [j for i in z for j in i if j ]
['abc', 'cmdh1521', '-x 123', '-y sadg', '-zzz 563sd']
>>>
```

Comment: Can I get the kind of parsing I want without having to resort to manually segmenting these individual strings like you have done?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you will have to use positive lookbehind regex as shown below:

```
(?<=-)(\w+) ([\w\d]+)
```

Description and example is at:
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR3oN8/1)